# Why sometimes class methods or fields marked erroneous(red underline) by IDE

Tags: delphi, ide

Sometimes some class methods or fields marked erroneous(that red underline) by IDE, but the project successfully compiled and executed(no error or warning).

If I hold mouse pointer on this erroneous sections I got this tool tip : "'TSomeClass' does not contain a member named 'SomeMethod'" or "Undeclared identifier 'SampleIdentifier'".

Is that a kind of IDE bug or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Error Insight has been like this since it was introduced. Better in some Delphi versions and worse in some. You can turn it off. See also [`Delphi XE shows at least 200 errors but the program compiles just fine`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6077190/576719).

Comment: Actually it can start to produce more accurate readings after real compilation pass has been made.

Comment: What is _real compilation_? What's its difference with normal compilation?  I get these errors until I restart IDE

Comment: Thanks, @LURD, I incorporated your link in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That feature is called Error Insight and [is known not to work reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077190/delphi-xe-shows-at-least-200-errors-but-the-program-compiles-just-fine). AFAIK you can't fix that. If it bothers you enough you'll have to [disable it](http://support.codegear.com/article/36055).

Comment: +1 This "Horror Insight" broken feature is just to be disabled. It saves both CPU and brain cells.

Comment: FWIW: I left it enabled for some months now (with D2007) and find it more helpful than annoying, despite some false positives. But I know I'm in the minority here. :-)

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez I'm agree with you. It's just a disturb tool. You get those errors when you just typing them. And just restarting the IDE will fix it. I think IDE just forgot to run UpdateErrorInsightDB like function sometimes.

Comment: @UliGerhardt In latest versions, it reports broken code everywhere, even within the RTL untils...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I found it when searching for a similar issue. I have a large project group with over a dozen packages, and Error Insight was broken for only one of them. The issue appeared after upgrading to `Delphi 10 Seattle`.

In `Project Options | Delphi Compiler`, make sure "`Use MSBuild externally to compile`" is false. This fixed the `Error Insight` behavior in my project.