# IDE underline bug when using Delphi 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I used Delphi 2010 on Windows XP. Then I migrated to Windows 7 - since then a strange thing happens:

Sometimes when part of the code has an error, the red underline is in the wrong position, as you can see in the below image. The underline was supposed to appear for `TModalResult`, but it appears much lower than expected:

[image: Delphi 2010 IDE: red underline vertically wrong]

But other than that, everything looks normal.

1. Does this happen to anyone else?
2. Do you know the reason?
3. Could this cause me problems in the future?

Comment: (1) Probably it happens to others as well. (2) The reason is that there is a bug in the IDE. (3) Yes, you might get annoyed by it.

Comment: kkkkkk @AndreasRejbrand Could this cause me problems in the future in relation the code?

Comment: A visual glitch in the IDE will not affect the compiler's output.

Comment: also : [Why sometimes class methods or fields marked erroneous(red underline) by IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18457576/327083)

Comment: [Pascal Delphi - Undeclared Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21483883/327083)